# Another word for "covered by"

Tags: single-word-requests

Take for example

My car is **covered by** insurance

Is there another word for this?

Comment: Why doesn't `covered by` work for you? Where do you need to use the word? Help us by providing more information and context.

Comment: It has to be a SINGLE word

Comment: In that case, can you give us an example sentence with a blank where you want the word? Otherwise, "My car is insured." would seem fine.

Comment: I don't see why you should need an alternative to the word that almost everyone uses in the cited context - ***protected*** would be the most credible alternative, but how is this a "real-world problem"?

Comment: Have you tried using a thesaurus?

Answer (score 1):

You can say:
***My car is insured.***

***insure***

If you insure yourself or your property, you pay money to an insurance company so that, if you become ill or if your property is damaged or stolen, the company will pay you a sum of money.

[V n] 
For protection against unforeseen emergencies, you insure your house, your furnishings and your car...

(From CollinsCobuild)